# Prove: $\cos^3{A} + \cos^3{(120°+A)} + \cos^3{(240°+A)}=\frac {3}{4} \cos{3A}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove that:

> $$\cos^3{A} + \cos^3{(120°+A)} + \cos^3{(240°+A)}=\frac {3}{4} \cos{3A}$$

My Approach:

$$\mathrm{R.H.S.}=\frac {3}{4} \cos{3A}$$
$$=\frac {3}{4} (4 \cos^3{A}-3\cos{A})$$
$$=\frac {12\cos^3{A} - 9\cos{A}}{4}$$

Now, please help me to continue from here.

Comment: I would expand $\cos(120^\circ + A)$ and $\cos(240^\circ + A)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also another more algebraic way. You can easily show (by expansion) that if $$a+b+c=0$$ then $$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$$
Since, in your problem, for every $A$ $$\cos{A}+\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}+\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}=0$$ Then you can use the above identity
$$\cos^3{A}+\cos^3{(A+2\pi/3)}+\cos^3{(A-2\pi/3)}=3\cos{A}\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}$$
By using the previously mentioned identity
$$\cos{x}\cos{y}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos{(x+y)}+\cos{(x-y)}\right)$$
you can simplify the RHS to this
$$\frac{3}{2}\cos{A}\left(\cos{(2A)}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
and then (using it again)
$$\frac{3}{4}\left(\cos{3A}+\cos{(A)}\right)-\frac{3}{4}\cos{A}=\frac{3}{4}\cos{(3A)}$$

Comment: How is $a+b+c=0$

Comment: This is a well-known identity. Just expand $\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}$ and $\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}$ (by using $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ formula) and then add $\cos{A}$ to see the terms cancel out each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this particular formula: $$\cos{x}\cos{y}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)\right)$$
twice and simplify $\cos^3{A}$, $\cos^3{(A+2\pi/3)}$, and $\cos^3{(A-2\pi/3)}$ in this way:
$$\begin{aligned} \cos^3{A}&=\cos{A}\left(\cos{A}\cos{A}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{A}\left(1+\cos{2A} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{A}+\frac{1}{2}\cos{A}\cos{2A}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{A}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\cos{A}+\cos{3A}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{A}+\frac{1}{4}\cos{A}+\frac{1}{4}\cos{3A}\\
\end{aligned}$$

And

$$\begin{aligned} \cos^3{(A+2\pi/3)}&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}\left(1+\cos{(2A+4\pi/3)} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}\left(1-\cos{(2A+\pi/3)} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}-\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}\cos{(2A+\pi/3)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\cos{(A-\pi/3)}-\cos{3A}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}-\frac{1}{4}\cos{(A-\pi/3)}+\frac{1}{4}\cos{3A}
\end{aligned}$$

And

$$\begin{aligned} \cos^3{(A-2\pi/3)}&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}\left(1+\cos{(2A-4\pi/3)} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}\left(1-\cos{(2A-\pi/3)} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}-\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}\cos{(2A-\pi/3)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\cos{(A+\pi/3)}-\cos{3A}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}-\frac{1}{4}\cos{(A+\pi/3)}+\frac{1}{4}\cos{3A}
\end{aligned}$$

Now, by adding the results and using the following identities you can get your answer (the second one can be proved by using the first identity in the reverse order).
$$\cos{A}+\cos{(A+2\pi/3)}+\cos{(A-2\pi/3)}=0$$
$$\cos{(A-\pi/3)}+\cos{(A+\pi/3)}=\cos{A}$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following picture. We see that the triangle with vertices $(\cos A, \sin A), (\cos(A+120^\circ), \sin(A+120^\circ)), (\cos(A+240^\circ), \sin(A+240^\circ))$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle with centriod at the origin.
[image]

Thus if we set $a = \cos A, b = \cos(A+120^\circ), c = \cos(A+240^\circ)$, then
\begin{align*}
a+b+c = 0
\end{align*}
and hence 
\begin{align*}
a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3abc
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\cos^3{A} + \cos^3{(120°+A)} + \cos^3{(240°+A)} &= 3\cos A \cos(A+120^\circ)\cos(A+240^\circ) \\
&= \frac{3}{2}(2\cos A \cos(A+120^\circ))\cos(A+240^\circ) \\
&= \frac{3}{2}[\cos(2A+120^\circ)+\cos(120^\circ)]\cos(A+240^\circ)\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\cos(2A+120^\circ)\cos(A+240^\circ)-\frac{3}{4}\cos(A+240^\circ)\\
&=\frac{3}{4}\cos(3A+360^\circ)+\frac{3}{4}\cos(A-120^\circ) -\frac{3}{4}\cos(A+240^\circ)\\
&=\frac{3}{4}\cos(3A)
\end{align*}
since $\cos(A+240^\circ) = \cos(360^\circ - (A+240^\circ)) = \cos(120^\circ -A) = \cos(A-120^\circ)$

Comment: If you can see geometrically, the points $(\cos A, \sin A), (\cos(120^\circ+A), \sin(120^\circ+A)), (\cos(240^\circ), \sin(240^\circ+A))$ are the vertices of an equilateral triangle with centroid as the origin, then the above proof holds since we have used only an algebraic identity.

Answer (score 1):

For the LHS, use $\cos(120^\circ +A)=\cos 120^\circ \cos A - \sin 120^\circ \sin A$

and $\cos(240^\circ+A)=\cos 240^\circ \cos A - \sin 240^\circ \sin A$

Then $\cos^3(120^\circ+A)=\left(\cos 120^\circ \cos A - \sin 120^\circ \sin A \right)^3$

and $\cos^3(240^\circ+A)=\left( \cos 240^\circ \cos A - \sin 240^\circ \sin A \right)^3$

Pop in values of $\cos 120^\circ$, $\sin 120^\circ$, etc before expanding brackets.

$\cos^3(120^\circ+A)=\left(-1/2 \cos A -\sqrt 3/2 \sin A \right)^3=-\frac 18 \left(\cos A +\sqrt 3 \sin A \right)^3$

and $\cos^3(240^\circ+A)=-\frac 18\left( \cos A - \sqrt3\sin A \right)^3$

Comment: It became quiet complex. Could you please suggest some convenient method?

Comment: Unless you want to use complex numbers (see other answer) you just have to persevere. Do you know how to use binomial expansions?

Comment: yes. I know about that.

Answer (score 1):

use that $$\cos(120^{\circ}+x)=-1/2\,\cos \left( x \right) -1/2\,\sqrt {3}\sin \left( x \right) $$
and $$\cos(240^{\circ}+x)=-1/2\,\cos \left( x \right) +1/2\,\sqrt {3}\sin \left( x \right) $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** As mentioned in the comments, substitute: $cos(120+A)$ and $sin(120+A)$ :$$\color{blue}{cos(120+A)=\dfrac{-1}{2}cosA-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}sinA}$$ 
$$\color{red}{cos(240+A)=\dfrac{-1}{2}cosA+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}sinA}$$

The L.H.S becomes:
$${cos}^3A +(\color{blue}{\dfrac{-1}{2}cosA-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}sinA})^3+(\color{red}{\dfrac{-1}{2}cosA+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}sinA})^3$$
Simplifying this further and using the fact that $\color{blue}{a}^3+\color{red}{b}^3=(\color{blue}{a}+\color{red}{b})(\color{blue}{a}^2-\color{blue}{a}\color{red}{b}+\color{red}{b}^2)$ we get:
$${cos}^3A-\dfrac{1}{4}{cos}^3A-\dfrac{9}{4}{sin}^2AcosA=\color{green}{\dfrac{3}{4}({cos}^3A+3{sin}^2AcosA)}$$

Note that the R.H.S is equal to:
$$\color{green}{\dfrac{3}{4}({cos}^3A+3{sin}^2AcosA)}$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\cos^3\theta=\frac34\cos\theta+\frac14\cos3\theta$. Observing that $$\cos(3A+3\cdot\tfrac23\pi)=\cos(3A+3\cdot\tfrac43\pi)=\cos3A,$$and adding the results of $\cos^3\theta$ for $\theta=A$, $\theta=A+\frac23\pi$, and $\theta=A+\frac43\pi$, using the fact that  $\cos A+\cos(A+\frac43\pi)=2\cos(A+\frac23\pi)\cos\frac23\pi=-\cos(A+\frac23\pi)$, now gives the required form.

Answer (score 0):

If $\cos3x=\cos3A$

$3x=n360^\circ\pm3A$ where $n$ is any integer

$x=n120^\circ+ A$ where $n=0,1,2$

As $\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x,$ the roots of $4c^3-3c-\cos3A=0$ are

$c_{n+1}=\cos(n120^\circ+ A)$ where $n=0,1,2$

Using Vieta's formula, $$c_1+c_2+c_3=0, c_1c_2c_3=\dfrac{\cos3A}4$$  $$\text{ and }c_1c_2+c_2c_3+c_3c_1=-\dfrac34$$

We need $c_1^3+c_2^3+c_3^3$

Now use $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

Comment: could you please put it a bit simply. I am just a 10th grade student.

Comment: @user354073, Please pinpoint your confusion

Comment: What is Vieta's formula?

Comment: @user354073, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas and   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103491/using-vietas-theorem-for-cubic-equations-to-derive-the-cubic-discriminant  and http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/polynomials/vietasFormulas.htm and many

Comment: Oh. Now its clear to me.

Comment: Could you please help me with this question. Please, I request you.
 math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895204/help-with-this-trigonometry-problem

Comment: @user354073, See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638874/factor-z7-1-into-linear-and-quadratic-factors-and-prove-that-cos-pi-7-c/638896

Comment: For which question is this link for?

Comment: @user354073, For the current one

Comment: Did you see the question I provided the link for?

Comment: Though the answer has been accepted but its not suitable for me to apply that. So, please provide a solution for me.

Comment: Hello, Are you there?

Are you providing answer or not?

Comment: @user354073, Change your voice first. You can't ask in such a tone.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. I don't have any intention like that. But could you please provide an answer?

Comment: @user354073, First unaccept the answer if you are not satisfied to draw the attention of others. I will try to answer if possible.

Comment: Ok. Just check once. I have unaccepted the answer. Please try to answer as soon as possible.