# Can we find the discriminant of a polynomial of any degree?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, discriminant

Some days ago I was solving a question which gave me a hard time. After doing some research I found out that it required the *Discriminant* of a *Cubic Equation*.

I looked up to the internet and I found out that the Discriminant of a Cubic Equation is $a^2b^2 + 18abc − 4b^3 − 4a^3c − 27c^2$.

**So I was wondering if we have a general formula for finding the Discriminant an Equation of any degree.**

I have been taught the discriminant of a Quadratic Equation where we prove it by Completing the Square method so *I was wondering if there was any method to find/prove if for Cubic Equations.*

*So, the 2 main Question I want to ask are,*

**How can we find/prove the Discriminant of a Cubic Equation?**

And,

**Can we find the Discriminant of any equation of any degree?**

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: The discriminant can be determined for polynomials with arbitary degree. But if the degree exceeds $4$, the roots cannot be calculated in general by radicals (Galois).

Comment: Oh, is there any general formula for finding the discriminant till the degree 4?

Comment: Enter poldisc ( a * x^4 + b * x^3 + c * x^2 + d * x + e ) in the pari/gp-calculator for the general formula for degree $4$, for example.

Comment: Note that the expression is very long already for degree $4$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your formula for the discriminant of a cubic equation is wrong. This formula is independent of $d$. (Assuming that you considered the cubic equation as $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$).
The correct formula for the discriminant is given by $D = b^2c^2-4ac^3-4b^3d-27a^2d^2+18abcd.$
Refer https://brilliant.org/wiki/cubic-discriminant/ for detailed proof.

Also, Have a look at a simiar question asked here: [Proof of the cubic discriminant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142934/proof-of-the-cubic-discriminant)

A general formula for finding the discriminant of an equation of any degree $(P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n−1}x^{n−1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ having roots $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$
is given by:

$D = a_n^{2n-2} \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}{(x_i-x_j)^2}.$

Moreover, you can refer to *Galois Theory by Ian Stewart*. The book has a nice treatment on the solution of polynomial equation in section $1.4$ of chapter $1$.